# firefox extention to check gmail apps that uses Google Applications Connector

Tags: gmail, firefox-extensions, gmail-imap, atlassian-crowd

is there any extension out there that would allow me to check my email that uses Google Applications Connector? http://www.atlassian.com/software/crowd/

I tried

- [WebMail Notifier](http://webmailnotifier.mozdev.org/drupal/) I have no idea why IMAP option doesn't work for me as I tried to connect to my email via IMAP from Thunderbird. And it worked.
- [Gmail Manager](http://www.longfocus.com/firefox/gmanager/)
- [Google Apps Mail Watcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/google-apps-mail-watcher/) - haven't tried after reading user comments